# How to wait [NSWorkspace recycleURLs] completion synchronously

Tags: cocoa

I need to move files on trash using [NSWorkspace recycleURLs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/recycleURLs%3acompletionHandler%3a) but I must wait completion, putting all code in the completionHandler isn't so simple, mainly because the method containing the call to recycleURLs must return a value.

I've found a dirty way to achieve the result but I would know if exists a better solution.
My solution uses a conditional variable and runloop

The code runs in a separated thread, not in main thread

```
__block BOOL waitCompletion = YES;
 void (^myCompletionHandler)(NSDictionary *newURLs, NSError *error) =
  ^(NSDictionary *newURLs, NSError *recycleError) {
      // do some stuff and before exits from method change waitCompletion value
        waitCompletion = NO;
};
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] recycleURLs:myURLToDelete
                 completionHandler:myCompletionHandler];
// loop until completionHandler finishes
while (waitCompletion && CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 2.0, true)) {
    ; //nop
}

// we can continue after recycleURLs
...
...
```

Comment: “I must wait [for] completion” Why?

Comment: The algorithm of my code requires to wait because it recursively takes care which file trash and do other stuff. I don't want to make the recursive call inside the completionHandler

Comment: Sounds like the solution is to make it non-recursive and then do it in the completion handler.